# TreeSet удалить дубликаты java

Tags: java, email, дублирование, treeset

Как удалить дубликаты из TreeSet?
Есть такой код:

```
import java.util.*;


public class EmailList {

    public static boolean validEmail(String email) {
        String ePattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@((\\[[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\])|(([a-zA-Z\\-0-9]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$";
        java.util.regex.Pattern p = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(ePattern);
        java.util.regex.Matcher m = p.matcher(email);
        return m.matches();
    }

   
     ArrayList<String> emailList = new ArrayList<>();

     private Set<String> list = new TreeSet<>();

    public void add(String email) {
        // TODO: валидный формат email добавляется
        if (!validEmail(email)){
            System.out.println(Main.WRONG_EMAIL_ANSWER);
            return;
        }

        emailList.add(email);
    }

    public List<String> getSortedEmails() {
        // TODO: возвращается список электронных адресов в алфавитном порядке
        for(String s: emailList) {

            list.addAll(emailList);
        }
        return new ArrayList<>(emailList);
    }

}
```

Comment: Отличительная особенность коллекций типа Set - отсутствие дубликатов

Answer (score 3):

Никак - их там уже нет - это же set.